# can't get rspec working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rspec

I was able to set up my rails project (rails version 3.2.7) and run rails generate rspec:install (rspec version 2.11.1). It also built the test files in the specs directory, but when I run "rspec", I get a bunch of errors starting:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
...
```

I also tried "bundle exec rspec", then the error is:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe bad config of test env database?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:test:prepare to load your schema in the test database before running RSpec?